# How can a system disc image be restored?

Tags: windows, backup, disk-image

The ability to create a system image of the system disc (with software such as Acronis True Image) makes sense - the operating system stays intact throughout the process.

But how will that image be restored if needed? Since the image includes the operating system files which, presumably, the disc imaging software needs to function.

**EDIT**

According to [Acronis' docs](http://dl2.acronis.com/u/pdf/ATI2015_userguide_en-US.pdf), section 5.1.2, it seems that creating a bootable media is *not* needed (as opposed to what was mentioned in an answer and comment to it here). So how does it do that?

Answer (score 1):

The image is restored by putting it on a bootable USB/HDD that you create through Acronis. Then you boot your machine from the device with your image and it will allow you to restore your system to that image.

Comment: So if I just save a system image of the disc onto an HDD (which contains additional stuff) - I can't restore it without first using some other computer to change that into a bootable HDD?

Comment: No;  You boot to the bootable media that Acronis creates.

Comment: You said "The image is restored by putting **it** on a bootable...". So what do you mean now "You boot to the bootable media that Acronis creates"? _Do_ I have to put the disc image on that bootable media or not? Acronis didn't create anything (besides the disc image file). EDIT: Oh, sorry. I didn't notice it wasn't you that commented. What you (Reeves) said _does_ make sense.